# Add border to img in overlay and close button or link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code which serves to open an image in an overlay div. For some reason whenever I try to add a border to the image object it doesn't work. It only comes out the raw image with no border. How can I implement a border on this and also a close button on top right?
This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.lightbox').click(function(e){

        $('body').css('overflow-y',' hidden');

        $('<div id="overlay"></div>')
        .css('top', $(document).scrollTop())
        .css('opacity', '0')
        .animate({'opacity': '0.6'}, 'slow')
        .appendTo('body');

        $('<div id= "lightbox"></div>')
        .hide()
        .appendTo('body');

        $('<img>', {
            src: $(this).attr('href'),
            load: function() {
                positionLightboxImage();
            },
            click : function() {
                removeLightbox();
            }
        }).appendTo('#lightbox');
        return false;
    });
});

function positionLightboxImage() {
  var top = ($(window).height() - $('#lightbox').height()) / 2;
  var left = ($(window).width() - $('#lightbox').width()) / 2;
  $('#lightbox')
    .css({
      'top': top + $(document).scrollTop(),
      'left': left
    })
    .fadeIn();
}

function removeLightbox() {
  $('#overlay, #lightbox')
    .fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $(this).remove();
      $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto'); // show scrollbars!
    });
}


<a class="lightbox" href="<?php echo $row_searchHH['imageURL']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row_searchHH['imageURL']; ?>" width="90" height="90" style="margin-left:10px" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your border to this chunk:

```
  $('#lightbox')
    .css({
      'top': top + $(document).scrollTop(),
      'left': left
    })
```

For example:

```
  $('#lightbox')
    .css({
      'top': top + $(document).scrollTop(),
      'left': left,
      'border': '2px solid white'
    })
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly. How can I add something like a description under the image??

Comment: How can I add something like a description under the image??

Comment: You could append an element like a div or paragraph to the lightbox did in the same way you appended the image to the lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vigneshvdm/J6dFj/1/) for demo
If you have the `img` inside the `div`
then probably you can set the style of the image

CSS

```
.imageclass{
width:98%;
height:98%;
    position:absolute;
    left:1%;
    top:1%;
}
.parentdivclass{
background:rgba(15, 15, 15, .5);
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    position:absolute;
}
.closebuttonclass
{
left:95%;
top:0.2%;
    width:5%;
    height:5%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

You can position your close button image on the top right of your div !!

so the final div structure should be something like this

HTML

```
<div class='parentdivclass'>
<img class='imageclass' src='' />
<img class='closebuttonclass' src='' />
</div>
```